# validate Select component using useField hook

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik, react-select

**I want to validate `Select` component.** but when I pass argument name for `useFeild` hook it said that name key is deprecated.
I also tried to pass object to the hook `useField({name: country}` its also not working!

I also tried to pass a string  `useField("country")` but I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getFieldProps')
```

---

This is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Formik, useField } from 'formik';
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  FormHelperText,
  TextField,
  makeStyles,
  Grid
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import countries from '../../profile/candidate/ProfileCreateView/PersonalInfo/countries';
import Select from 'react-select';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({}));

const StepTwo = ({
  className,
  formValues,
  handleNextStep,
  handleChangeOnParent,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [helpers] = useField(name="country"); 
  const { setValue, setTouched, setError } = helpers;

  const onSubmitHandler = async (
    values,
    { resetForm, setErrors, setStatus, setSubmitting }
  ) => {
    try {
      const {
        country: { text: country },
      } = values;
      handleNextStep(2, {
        country,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      setStatus({ success: false });
      setErrors({ submit: err.message });
      setSubmitting(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        country: formValues.country || '',
      }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        country: Yup.object().required('Countrey is required'),
  
      })}
      onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}
      enableReinitialize
    >
      {({
        errors,
        handleBlur,
        handleChange,
        handleSubmit,
        setFieldValue,
        isSubmitting,
        touched,
        values
      }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Select
                styles={customStyles}
                placeholder="Country"
                name="country"
                value={values.country}
                options={countries}
                getOptionLabel={option => option.text}
                onChange={option => {
                  setValue(option.value) 
                  setTouched(true)
                  setError(undefined)
                  setFieldValue('country', option);
                  handleChangeOnParent('country', option);
                }}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

StepTwo.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string
};

export default StepTwo;
```

Comment: From their doc, https://formik.org/docs/api/useField
it seems like you need to send a string, did you try "useField('country')"?

Comment: I tried it but I got this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getFieldProps')